# How to execute base error handler in dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I've got a project using dropzone.js to accept multiple file uploads. Everything works fine, except that we would like to supplement the built-in error behaviour. The dropzone is instantiated programmatically in JS (rather than autodiscover) so that we can add a handler for the error event:

```
        this.fileDropzone = new Dropzone("#fileDropzone", {
            paramName: "files",
            maxFilesize: maxSizeInMb,
            uploadMultiple: false,
            acceptedFiles: mimeTypes,
            success: function (file : any) {
                fileDropzone.removeFile(file);
                refreshLibrary();
            },
            error: function () {
                // do something here   <<-------
            }
        }
```

The issue is, my error handler overrides the default behaviour. I no longer get the error message or the "X" mark on any failed files. To be fair, this is what I would expect to happen - dropzone assumes I want to replace the standard error handling.

However, I want to supplement behaviour and then call the base error handler so I get all the normal behaviour.

How can I achieve this?